# How set alarm on specific day and reschedule it repeatedly weekly  

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alarm, uilocalnotification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
   return;

localNotif.fireDate = selected;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

if (isSun) {
    [components setWeekday:1];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}

if (isMon) {
    [components setWeekday:2];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];   
}

if (isTue) {
    [components setWeekday:3];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}

if (isWed) {
    [components setWeekday:4];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:NSWeekCalendarUnit];
}

if (isThu) {
    [components setWeekday:5];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}

if (isFri) {
    [components setWeekday:6];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}

if (isSat) {
    [components setWeekday:7];
    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}
```

I want to set alarm on selected date and please correct my code i am new in iphone.
help me.

Comment: have u done with setting alarm on specific days.i am also working on it.But i am totally confused .can u help me on how to do it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly see this Sample from Apple iOS Developer Library:

[Scheduling, Registering, and Handling Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)

Comment: How do i reschedule it repeatedly weekly.

Comment: @Rahul Salvikar: Are not you going to notify the user when the alarm is ready? then you will receive UILocalNotification meesage, reset the alarm Again in the background for the next week.

Comment: @Rahul Salvikar: Any Updates regarding your issue?